# How can I get UDID using liblockdown.dylib?

Tags: xcode, ios, udid

I try to get the UDID without using the `UIDevice` class but directly from implementing the dynamic library `liblockdown.dylib` on iOs 4.2. I don't find any documentation. All I need is to get the `kLockdownUniqueDeviceIDKey`, what should I do ?

Comment: did you see my answer about libMobileGestalt?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about iOS 4, but I know that the UDID can also be retrieved on iOS 5, 6 and 7 using the libMobileGestalt.dylib. More information about this library can be found on the [iPhone Development Wiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/LibMobileGestalt.dylib).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [header](http://code.google.com/p/chronicdev/wiki/LibLockdownHeader) for the liblockdown.dylib

Answer (score 0):

here implementation:
https://github.com/theiostream/lockdown-uiduid/blob/master/main.mm

This code work on iOS 6.1.3 but it does not work on iOS 7b2 :(

Comment: And I assume it still doesn't work on the released versions of iOS 7? I can't even find liblockdown.dylib anymore, perhaps the functions were moved to another library.